# Lenovo G580 (20150)- Geforce drivers from Lenovo won't install

Tags: drivers, lenovo-laptop, nvidia-geforce, display-driver

I've got Lenovo G580 (20150) and I'm trying to install the geforce graphics card present in the system. I don't know exactly what the gpu model is but it's something akin to Geforce 610M. I've got Windows 8.1 installed and the drivers from Lenovo support page for this laptop don't work (I tried drivers for Win 8.1/8/7). During installation the drivers installer says that it "couldn't find appropriate hardware".

I also tried various drivers from sites like driveridentifier but none worked. I even installed Win 10 and Windows Update found but couldn't install the drivers. I also have  Win 8.1 freshly installed. It's definitely not an OS problem. I also don't have recovery dvds/partition...

Here are the graphics identifiers:
PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1140&SUBSYS_397717AA&REV_A1

PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1140&SUBSYS_397717AA

PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1140&CC_030200

PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_1140&CC_0302

Comment: [g580 specs](http://www.lenovo.com/shop/emea/content/pdf/Essential/GSeries/en/essential-g580-datasheet.pdf) suggest either GT610m or GT630m on that model.  have you tried [Nvidia's official drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I did try the official drivers. They don't find appropriate hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak english very well. but your probleme is simple.
if your PC is lenovo G580 20150 then you certainly have the Nvidia GeForce 610M Optimus.

1) download Intel HD graphics 4000 and install it normally (Intel Video driver from lenovo PC support).

2) download graphics driver Nvidia VGA for G580 20157 from lenovo PC support also.

3) install Nvidia driver ( it will probabely chow you nothing after pressing the "finish" botton because of a bug in the executable). so you have to install it for real from the folder C:\Drivers\Nvidia VGA Driver 7(64-bit).